Generalized solutions for $1 + 4^x + 4^y = z^2$
Problem
The motivation of this question is to generalize Michael Penn's Video.
Let $m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $m$ is even. Notice that for $m = 2$, Michael already explained it. Therefore, fix an $m$ with $m \geq 4$. So, I want to find all solutions for $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that
$$1 + m^{2x} + m^{2y} = z^2$$
My attempt
Since RHS is a perfect square, the LHS is also a perfect square. WLOG, $y \geq x$. Write $m = 2^p q$ such that $p \geq 2$ and $q$ is a positive odd integer and suppose $z = m^y +1$.
Then, $(m^{y} + 1)^{2} = m^{2y} + 2m^y + 1$; so, $2m^y = m^{2x}$. This is where I get stuck:
I need to solve the following equivalent equation:
$$2^{py + 1} q^y= 2^{2px} q^{2x} \label{MP} \tag{$*$}$$
Does $\eqref{MP}$ have a solution?

If $q$ is an odd integer and $p, x, y$ are integers, by unique factorization
$2^{py+1} q^y = 2^{2px} q^{2x}$ iff $py+1 = 2px$ and $y=2x$.  But then $py+1$ is odd while $2px$ is even, so this is impossible.

Well, can $p$ and $y$ be even?

Oh! I see! If $p$ divides the RHS of $2px$, then $p$ must also divide the LHS (i.e., $py +1$). This implies that $p =1$. This contradicts the assumption that $p \geq 2$ in the first place! Thanks!

But is there another solution except when $z = m^y + 1$?
